# Hide and show button javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript any advice will be really much appreciated I am trying to hide my button  and show it based in the value that been loaded to a field but my below code is not working

there is  a field named ook if page loaded there will be a value display in ook it depends on the database but it will be loaded in page I want my button to hide if value is not yes

```
    $(document).ready( function(){

           var k = FormUtil.getField("ook").val();

           if ( k ='YES') {

               $("#btn).show();

           } else {  $("#btn).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why is your code all over the place like that? Please use the refactoring/beautifier utilities of your IDE.

Comment: I am only beginner I am trying to learn it thank you for the advice

Comment: There are a few syntax errors with this code that you should fix first.  #1) Your `$(function(){}` is missing a closing `);`  #2) Your `else {` is missing a closing `}`.  #3) Your `$("#btn)` is missing the `"` to make it correctly written as `$("#btn")`

Comment: Also, `$(document).ready()` and `$(function(){})` are effectively the same thing, so you are doing the same thing twice.  You only need one of those, so pick which one you like better and remove the other.

Comment: I see thank you for pointing it out

Comment: condition is wrong - use `==` instead of `=` to check equality

Comment: Thank you I change condition its working

Comment: use like this $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var k = FormUtil.getField("ook").val();
    if (k == 'YES') {
        $("#btn").show();
    } else {
        $("#btn").hide();
    }
})

Comment: Thnaks @Taplar  i make it correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $(function(){



           var k = FormUtil.getField("ook").val();

       if ( k ='YES')
       {

           $("#btn).css("display" ,"block")




           } else {  $("#btn).css("display ,"none")
```

}

```
});



});
```

Comment: It may be helpful to include a short explanation of your code.

Comment: Yes, explanation of above-mentioned code is You can hide or show of your div using method .css() of jQuery.

Comment: Have you checked the value of "k" when page is load , if value is not assigned then you can set false as a default value & then check ook filed return value

Comment: Oh, sorry. Please  the else part with   $("#btn").css("display ,"none")

Comment: @sonal.paghdal bottom left of your post there is an 'edit' button that you can use to edit and fix your post.

Comment: Thank you very much all for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in condition `( k ='YES')`, also in `$("#btn)` selectors

```
$(document).ready( function(){

       var k = FormUtil.getField("ook").val();

       if ( k == 'YES') {

           $("#btn").show();

       } else {  
           $("#btn").hide();
       }
});
```